# How to split CodePen into webpacked Components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-transition

I am following this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/timrijkse/pen/ALgZpp),
and trying to fit it into the default VueJS 2.0 Boilerplate. This is how I would split the files up:

```
App.vue
main.js
components/Transitions.vue
components/Controls.vue
components/Page.vue
```

I am having huge problems getting this to run. E.g. my App.vue does not find the `state`. This is how I defined it in **main.js**:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const state = {
    animations: ['fade', 'slide', 'slideUp', 'zoom', 'flipX', 'flipY'],
    view: 'slide'
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return this.state
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is my **App.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <component :is="state.view">
      <h1>{{ state.view }}</h1>
    </component>
    <controls></controls>
  </div>
</template>
```

This would be my controls:

```html
<template id="controls">
<ul class="controls">
  <li v-for="(animation, index) in state.animations" v-bind:key="index" @click.prevent="setView(animation)" v-bind:class="{ 'active': animation === state.view }">
    {{ animation }}
  </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  template: '#controls',

  methods: {
    setView(animation) {
      this.state.view = animation
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

..and so forth. Unfortunately I am getting:

```
[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

(found in <Root>) vue.runtime.esm.js:619
[Vue warn]: Property or method "state" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.state is undefined"
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to get this thing to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching data properties to the root instance does not make them globally available in all descendant components (which appears to be what you attempted). There are actually a few ways to share state across components, including [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [global event bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) (e.g., using [`$root.emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) and [`$root.on()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on)). However, another simple solution is to use [Vue.observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) along with a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), exported from a shared file:

*stateMixin.js:*

```js
import { observable } from "vue";

const state = observable({
  animations: ["fade", "slide", "slideUp", "zoom", "flipX", "flipY"],
  view: "slide"
});

// a mixin that declares a data propety named `state`
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state
    };
  }
};
```

Then, you could import that file into any component that needs to access `state`:

*App.vue:*

```js
import stateMixin from '@/stateMixin'

export default {
  mixins: [stateMixin],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.state.view) // <-- stateMixin provides access to `state`
  }
}
```

[demo of that Codepen in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-blackburn-qv339?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

---

Also note that since you're converting to single-file-components (SFC), you should not export a `template` property. The SFC itself declares the template already, and the compiler knows to use that by default.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I achieved it in the meanwhile with vuex. VueJS is great.

Answer (score 1):

You could return that `state` by applying spread operator as follows :

```
const state = {
    animations: ['fade', 'slide', 'slideUp', 'zoom', 'flipX', 'flipY'],
    view: 'slide'
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return {...state} 
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: How would this solve the problem that multiple files cannot access variables declared in other files?

Comment: if you're sharing data between multiple files try to use `props`, `emit` or `vuex`, i just answered the error of reading state data property, please check my updated answer and this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cloud-1nw4o)

Comment: I don't think its helpful to give a partial answer (without mentioning this fact) to the question that still gives the exact same error message even if the author implements your solution.

Comment: it might not be helpful for the first time but trying my answer and posting other details we could clarify that better

Comment: I did as you did in your example and got exactly same error, only now it says msg not defined. Could you take a look at the example CodePen I posted? Appreciate it!

Comment: the codepen example that you provided doesn't contain that error